# UICollectionView autoscroll on UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

When using `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` with horizontal and vertical scrolling,

how do i get the corresponding `UISCrollView` from `UICollectionView`

to automatically scroll a given section (`setContentOffset`) by timer

eg. so only **ONE** section is automatically scrolled, not the whole collectionView

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the same problem that I don’t know how to scroll my orthogonal section.

Answer (score 0):

Right after I posted my comment, I realized that there is a `scrollToItem:at:at:animated:` method on `UICollectionView`. At least it works for me, but I only have one orthogonal section in my collection view.

I am not sure if that’s what you want (scrolling to a specific index path) or if you want to scroll a specific section to a specific offset without an index path.

Note: There seems to be a bug with iOS 14. Trying to scroll to the index path that is just **before** the current visible one actually scrolls one further. In iOS 13.X it works as expected.